# Convolutions, when can I combine integrals together?

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform, convolution

In reading a theorem about convolutions, this was presented, but I am confused as to when can we combine integrals as shown in line 2[image: v]

Comment: @david what do you think?

Comment: Usually in a course on measure theory, these kind of results would be presented alongside [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Joppy does that mean this is a legal move